# Disable table of contents for documents

Tags: docbook, tableofcontents

I am using DocBook 4.5 and wanted to customize whether or not the table of contents is generated. I was looking over the XSD but couldn't find a way to disable it. I found ways to customize it.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both [Docbook 2](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/toc.html) and [Docbook 5](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/toc.html) the `toc` element documenation says:

> "In real life, tocs are usually generated automatically by the presentation system and never have to be represented explicitly in the document source."

So the next question is, which presentation system are you using?

---

Since you're using FOP (which I haven't used too much), I get the impression from [this documentation](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/TOCcontrol.html) that you can just pass `generate.toc=nop` on the command line to suppress building a table of contents.  See also this [Google groups page](http://groups.google.com/group/asciidoc/browse_thread/thread/1badad21ff9447ac?pli=1).

Comment: Define presentation system. Not entirely sure that that means.

Comment: What are you using to convert your Docbook XML to pdf/html/tex/chm/etc?

Comment: He's saying that docbook doesn't generate the toc, it's whatever word processing system you're using.

Comment: Oh. I am using apache FOP. I will look through their documentation.

Comment: was able to pass generate.toc=nop directly to the transformer via the setParam(String paramName, Object value) and that did the trick. Awesome! Thanks a lot!