# Docbook - suppressing TOC

Tags: html, docbook

I am converting a docbook to an html using 1.77 xsl transformation. But when it is transformed it automatically generates a Table of Contents.  How do you change this behavior?

I have found this:  [Disable table of contents for documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088063/disable-table-of-contents-for-documents)

So I am guessing that html xsl transform would be the presentation system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborate DocBook formatting is meant to be customized using an xsl stylesheet.

#### See Also

[Writing a DocBOok Customization Layer for Formatting](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/www.sagehill.net/xml/docbookxsl/CustomMethods.html#CustomDriverFile)

[Customizing Table Of Contents Using XSL](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/www.sagehill.net/xml/docbookxsl/GeneralCustoms.html#TOCcontrol)

#### customize_formatting.xsl: Example DocBook XSL Customization Layer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="1.0"> <!-- change this to 2.0 if your tools support it -->
    <xsl:import href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/fo/docbook.xsl"/>

    <!--uncomment this to suppress toc when using XSL 1.0 or 2.0
    <xsl:param name="generate.toc">article</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="generate.toc">book</xsl:param>
    -->

    <!--uncomment this to suppress toc when using XSL 2.0
    <xsl:param name="generate.toc">
        article nop
        book nop
    </xsl:param>
    -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### How to Use customize_formatting.xsl

Point your tools to use customize_formatting.xsl instead of the off-the-shelf docbook.xsl.  Then, put all your formatting customizations in the body of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` section.

For TOC suppression, you can just uncomment the appropriate line.

There is a quirk with some (or maybe all) XSL 1.0 tools that seem to prevent them from handling the whitespace-separated pairs used in the body of `<xsl:param name="generate.toc">`.  I have had success suppressing TOC by just using the single word `article` or `book` instead of the proper whitespace separated pairs.

Answer (score 1):

When transforming, you can use the `Transformer#setParameter(String, Object)` method to specify no TOC generation like this:

```
transformer.setParameter("generate.toc", "nop");
```